# Can I use sclite to compare two txt files?

Tags: terminal

That is, I'm not comparing transcripts, just two plain text files. I put this in the terminal:

`sctk-2.4.10/bin/sclite -r files/ref.txt -h files/hyp.txt "txt" -i rm`

But it says:

`Error: Unable to score 'txt' against 'trn'`

If I don't use `-i` option I get

`sclite: Error, Required utterance id (option -i) for transcript mode`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: What is the format within the hyp file?